# java.util.MissingResourceException while running jUnit in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, junit

**Error Trace**

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name logi4j, locale ja_JP
*at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResouceException(Unknown Souce)*

**Junit file**

```
@RunWith(SpringJunit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml")
@PropertySource("file:WEB-INF/prop/log4j/log4j.properties")
public class SearchServiceTest {

   @Autowired
   private SearchService service;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception{}

   @After
   public void tearDown() throws Exception{}

   @Test
   public void testService() {
      // Resource bundle is loaded inside this service and throws exception
      service.execute();
   }
}
```

Service method is properly called from Junit and executing. Moreover the same program is working when deployed in application server.

The problem could be property files are not in class path. So I have added PropertySource annotation to load the property file but Junit is not able to recognize the files. I have also tried by using @PropertySource("classpath*:WEB-INF/prop/log4j/log4j.properties") but it is not working.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to use a property source to load log4j properties is pretty much pointless. Why would you need those files to configure spring? Anyway for starters add the fullstrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: @M. Deinum. I am new to jUnit along with spring. service file internally called many resource files (like log4j.properties, searchTool.properties...etc) and those property files are not loaded by default. I am having the trace in remote machine. So not able to provide you the full trace. Sorry for inconvenience. If you could give a hint of how to configure resource files in jUnit it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: Solved this issue by adding classpath in eclipse run configuration.     1. Open run dialog (click the little arrow next to the play button and go to run configurations)
 2. Go to the "classpath" tab
3. Select the "User Entries" and click the "Advanced" button on the right side.
4. Now select the "Add External folder" radio button.
5. Select the resources folder